# Convert milliseconds to yyyy-MM-dd date-time format in Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to convert milliseconds (e.g : 1503478800000) to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' (e.g : 2017-08-23T09:00:000Z) date-time format.
Milliseconds value stored in the Soapui Global variable.

```
def testCase = messageExchange.modelItem.testCase;
def NewDateTime = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("StartDateTime").toInteger();
log.info NewDateTime.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Error popup display :-

```
For input string: "1503478800000"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With Groovy you can do it with [`Date.format(String format)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) method, e.g.

```
def millis = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("StartDateTime").toLong()

log.info new Date(millis).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

Comment: I tried this : `def aaa = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("StartDateTime");
log.info aaa.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");` Output : `Tue Aug 22 16:13:26 IST 2017:INFO:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
`

Comment: @rAJ Try applying a hint from updated answer. I hope it helps.